# CakePHP 3: CounterCache with BelongsToMany

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, counter-cache, cakephp-3.1

I have a `BelongsToMany` association, my tables are `PostsTable`, `TagsTable` and `PostsTagsTable`.

As explained [here in the CakePHP book (associations)](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations), I have this fields:

```
tags.id, tags.tag, tags.post_count
posts_tags.id, posts_tags.tag_id, posts_tags.post_id
```

Everything works correctly for now.
So, as you can understand, now I want to use the `tags.post_count` field with `CounterCache`.

I followed the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html), but I suppose this is a special case, in fact it doesn't work by simply adding the behavior to the `PostsTable`.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html#advanced-usage)

> The CounterCache behavior **works for belongsTo associations only**. For example for “Comments belongsTo Articles”, you need to add the CounterCache behavior to the CommentsTable in order to generate comment_count for Articles table.
>   **It is possible though to make this work for belongsToMany associations.** You need to enable the CounterCache behavior in a custom through table configured in association options. See how to configure a custom join table Using the ‘through’ Option.

**UPDATE**

- Bake your PostsTags model
- Add CounterCache behavior in your PostsTagsTable
- [Use the ‘through’ Option](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option)

Comment: sorry @Salines, the `post_count` field on the `post_tags' table? Are you sure?

Comment: I write you what it says in the cakephp book. But what you need is the sum of posts for each tag, where habtm relationship between tags and posts?

Comment: yes, sure, I want just a count of post for each tag