# Count BelongToMany relationship in CakePHP 3.2

Tags: cakephp

I have a Table A related many to many with a Table B and I want to know how many related rows I have in B with a given A entity.
In SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AB WHERE A_id=1;
```

I thought that I should place it in the model of A with a Virtual Field that retrieves the count, but I didn´t find a way to use the model itself to get the related B rows.

I tried with

```
$this->contain(['B'])->count()
```

But it didn't work because 'contain' is undefined. So, how should I get the count?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3: CounterCache with BelongsToMany](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948513/cakephp-3-countercache-with-belongstomany)

Comment: @Salines Well, it seems that it makes what i wanted but, why should I store the count in the relationship table?

Comment: Your relationship Model with CounterCache behavior are not store count in own table, but related, in your case in A table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that u put the association in both of your models initialize method and dont call contain() on $this.

```
$query = $this->A->find();

numberOfRecords = $query->contain(['B'])->count;
```

Comment: "Call to a member function find() on null". It seems that the Entity doesn´t have an instance of the the Table collection that contains himself.

Comment: Please supply the model init. method and the controller method of A where you are calling the function.